# Absolute paths for React app on Github CI with Firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, continuous-integration, firebase-hosting, github-ci

After [switching to use absolute paths](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports), although my local builds still work fine, Github CI build fails with this error:

```
./src/App.js
Cannot find module: 'components/Layout'. Make sure this package is installed.
```

How can I make Firebase/Github CI also search the `src` directory?

Comment: could you share the build command that is executed in CI and locally? also, the assumption is that create-react-app is used, correct?

Comment: Yes, create-react-app is used. Build command: 
npm install && CI=false npm run build.
Same with local: npm run build

Comment: Have you created a `.env` file at the root with inside `NODE_PATH=src/` ?

Comment: I did try that although it's been deprecated in favor of jsconfig.json.

Message in build:
```Setting NODE_PATH to resolve modules absolutely has been deprecated in favor of setting baseUrl in jsconfig.json (or tsconfig.json if you are using TypeScript) and will be removed in a future major release of create-react-app.
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating [jsconfig.json](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports) with the following configuration should do the trick:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I've tried creating a sample repo with the setup you mentioned and GitHub actions (I hope this is what you meant by GitHub CI) job did create build properly.

Comment: That is exactly what I have (same as the link in the question). I'm using firebase to set up the CI (Github action). This is what I followed: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#firebase

Comment: I followed the instructions and was able to set this up, check out https://github.com/ten-sis/so-absolute-paths/pull/1. I'm going to remove the repo in a couple of weeks. I had to switch from yarn to npm because `npm ci` command required package-lock.json. If you still have the same error, maybe try double-checking your repo that all the configs are matching what's in my repo.

Comment: could you change one of your css imports to absolute and try?

Comment: Figured out my mistake. I had some files that were lower case in remote but upper case in local. My filesystem is not case sensitive, so local builds didn't fail, but CI runs on ubuntu which is case sensitive. Awarding the bounty as a thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

"Figured out my mistake. I had some files that were lower case in remote but upper case in local. My filesystem is not case sensitive, so local builds didn't fail, but CI runs on ubuntu which is case sensitive." - Arash

This is the solution, I have the same error and can fix it by doing the above.